# Google custom search API giving a 405 error for a post request

Tags: google, google-api

My website has a chatbot on it.   This bot is attempting to do a POST request to the google custom search tool.  I have a custom search page set up already.

When I make the POST request, I receive a 405 error. Does Google allow POST requests to the custom search tool?

I am doing a POST from Manychat if that changes anything.

Comment: What is a "push request"?    I know about "push notifications", but I can't think of a scenario in which "push" would be appropriate far a custom search.   Maybe you actually mean a POST request?

Comment: You are correct its a Post request I am attempting to fill the search field with text entered into the chatbot.

Answer (score 2):

I was posting the wrong kind of json took me days to solve but I got it google custom search only excepts get requests to the googleapi.com/customserach url.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and letting us know what was wrong.